# Translate a rotated image into a Rectangle Left Top Corner

Tags: canvas, rotation, draw, trigonometry

I wrote an application that draws SMT Trays and the components that fill them. I succeed to import a rotation procedure that rotate and draw my electronic component figurine in the center coordinate with an alpha rotation angle(see the below image). I need to translate the 00 cordinate of the figurine with an X,Y offset to draw the entire rotated figurine in the rectangle.

```
So I only know the:
figurine rotation angle: dbRotationAngle
figurine X,Y position: dbX, dbY
figurine Width, Height: dbWidth, dbHeight
Rectangle LeftTop corner Position:  (LeftTop.X, LeftTop.Y)
```

[image]

So my question is: How to calculate the offsets X,Y of the rotated figurine in order to draw the entire image within the rectangle that starts at the (LeftTop.X, LeftTop.Y)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Finding the Extent**

You need to transform the corners and then find the min and max

So start with a box that will be rendered at its center point

```
var box = {
   top:0,
   left:0,
   bottom:100,
   right:200,
   centerX:100,  // the position in the box that the render coordinates are.
   centerY:50
}
```

You have a rotation in radians that the box will be. Its X and Y axis will be rotated by this amount.

```
var rotation = ?
```

And you need the coordinates of the 4 corners.

First workout the the vector along the object's rotated x axis

```
var axisX_x = Math.cos(rotation);
var axisX_y = Math.sin(rotation);
```

This also gives us the vector along the object's y rotated  axis. Which is at 90deg clockwise from the x axis.

```
var axisY_x = -axisX_y;
var axisY_y = axisX_x;
```

Now to the top left corner. We need to find the distance it is from the object's center of rotation.

```
var x = box.left - box.centerX;
var y = box.top - box.centerY;
```

Now transform the point by moving it along the two vectors representing the rotated axis. Move x along the X axis and y along the y axis.

```
var tx = x*axisX_x + y * axisY_x;
var ty = x*axisX_y + y * axisY_y;
```

Now because we want the extent of the box we need to save the min and max;

```
var minX = tx;
var miny = ty;
var maxX = tx;
var maxy = ty;
```

The next point is the top right which is along the object's x axis so move along it the width of the box

```
tx = tx + axisX_x * (box.right - box.left); // (box.right - box.left) is the
ty = ty + axisX_y * (box.right - box.left); // width of the box
```

Now we need to check the min max

```
minX = Math.min(minX, tx);
minY = Math.min(minY, ty);
maxX = Math.max(maxX, tx);
maxY = Math.max(maxY, ty);
```

Now move down the Y axis by the object's height and get the min max of the objects rotated bottom right corner.

```
tx = tx + axisY_x * (box.bottom - box.top);
ty = ty + axisY_y * (box.bottom - box.top);
minX = Math.min(minX, tx);
minY = Math.min(minY, ty);
maxX = Math.max(maxX, tx);
maxY = Math.max(maxY, ty);
```

Only one point left the bottom left, so move back along the X axis by the object's width and get the min max

```
tx = tx - axisX_x * (box.right - box.left);
ty = ty - axisX_y * (box.right - box.left);
minX = Math.min(minX, tx);
minY = Math.min(minY, ty);
maxX = Math.max(maxX, tx);
maxY = Math.max(maxY, ty);
```

Now the min and max values hold the extent of the box relative to its center

To draw the box so that it is inside the top left corner of the required container with some padding

```
var pad = 2; // two pixels from the edge
var containerLeft = 100;
var containerTop = 100;

var boxX = containerLeft - minX + pad;
var boxY = containerTop - minY + pad;
```

Now `boxX` and `boxY` hold the location the center of the box needs to be to be tucked up in the top left of the container. With the min and max you can fit the box anywhere inside the containing area.

That was the detailed explanation and can be reduced with a function or two and if you only need to fit the top right then you only need the `minX` and `minY`.

Comment: And the box is a Regional of Interest of the figurine? Right?

Comment: The box is the object you want to move the container is the area that the box will end up inside.